# Trouble using Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-apps

I am trying to use FB App for auto posting. I have been trying to use the SDK from  facebookapi as well as facebook-php-sdk-master

However, i am having trouble with setting up the Uris and domains on the FB App settings. I have tried all combinations  - with 'localhost', with actual site domain 'landshoppe.com', with 'www', without 'www' etc. I am not able to understand what exactly needs to be entered into the Uri fields !

If somebody can explain and help me get the script working, I will be obliged.

I am attaching screenshots of what I am doing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the Basic FB settings, I have tried adding http://localhost as well as http://landshoppe.com

In the Site Url also I have tried same

In the Advanced settings, redirect Deauthorize Callback URL also I have tried these Uris

I have whitelisted IPs 127.0.0.1 and my server IP

Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login and
Embedded Browser OAuth Login tabs say 'Yes'

I have got 'http://localhost/fb-tokens/' in Valid OAuth redirect URIs

My Script settings are

```
$appid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$appsecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pageId = '530139960390619';
$msg = 'Buy/Sell/rent Property in India. Redevelopment, Joint Ventures, Auction Properties';
$title = 'Landshoppe-The Property Destination';
$uri = 'http://localhost/'; //I have tried all combinations here
$desc = 'Buy an Apartment, Rent an Apartment,Land for Redevelopment, Land     for sale, Commercial Property';
$pic = 'http://www.landshoppe.com/images/logo.jpg';
$action_name = 'Post to FB';
$action_link = 'http://www.landshoppe.com/';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $appid,
'secret' => $appsecret,
'cookie' => false,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Contact Facebook and get token
if ($user) {
// you're logged in, and we'll get user acces token for posting on the wall
try {
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");
if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
'message' => $msg,
'name' => $title,
'link' => $uri,
'description' => $desc,
'picture'=>$pic,
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' =>        $action_link))
 );

$status = $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", "post", $attachment);
} else {
$status = 'No access token recieved';
}
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
} else {
// you're not logged in, the application will try to log in to get a access      token
header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>           'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 }

echo $status;
```

I am getting errors like

>
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
>

And

>
'Cannot Load Url' because it is not added in App Domains'

>

I am at my wits end ! Kindly help me understand what needs to be the Uris that should be used in all these places.

Comment: why would you whitelist localhost? you should be very careful with that setting, if you have a dynamic IP, you will not be able to access your app again. that setting is only for accessing the app settings and nothing else. you really only need to add the website platform and the app domain.

Comment: @luschn otherwise it is throwing error saying domain is not white listed and i am testing from local machine !

Comment: where is your code? that would be very important. also, are you using any port on localhost?

Comment: @luschn I have updated the code

Comment: you activated "require app secret" for server calls, but you don´t do that in your code. read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Comment: @luschn I have tried deactivating that too. Still error says Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. I feel I am not using the right URIs in the right places.....could you check that for me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111199/discussion-between-user3526204-and-luschn).

Comment: you have not answered one of my questions: are you using any port on localhost?

Comment: btw, which sdk version are you using? it looks like a very old one.

Comment: No... I am not using any port on localhost. Maybe it is the SDK ? But still, could you tell me what URIs should I be actually entering into the appropriate fields in App Settings and my script...maybe I am doing wrong there.. ?

Comment: so...on which port does your localhost webserver run? you do need to add the port in the "site url". the rest looks fine. don´t change anything in the app settings unless you know exactly what it does though.

Comment: @luschn thanks for your time and effort i have added port no.80 but still same situation. Hope to find a resolution soon.